# Windows 7 Batch File to Launch a VMWARE Instance with GUI

Tags: windows, user-interface, batch-file, vmware, reboot

I have a Windows 7 host machine with a VMWARE Workstation 9 based guest operating instance. What I need is that the guest OS to not only run but runs inside the guest in the VMWARE Workstation gui upon a host reboot--say, from a power failure. I have tried all solutions online but so far I am unable to make the GUI to appear--though the guest OS *does* launch.

Here is my solution so far: I have created a .bat file and setup Windows Task Scheduler to start the .bat program. Here is what's inside the batch file:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation"
vmrun start  "C:\VirtualMachines\WindowsServer2012_std_ArcGISVM2\Windows Server 2012 Std.vmx" gui
```

Note, I am using '`vmrun`' program but using other online solutions which use the VM Ware Workstation's executable doesn't help with the gui part either. And adding or removing the '`gui`' flag doesn't seem to make any difference.

Also note, I'd rather not use the Workstation as a Server in a 'shared' virtual machine setup. There should be a simpler way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Edited/Detailed Answer Below**]

Never mind. I did end up creating a Shared VM per the instructions from another site (whose link is not working anymore!)

Here is how I accomplished this:

1. Using VMWare Workstation gui, pressed F9 to bring up option to enable Sharing of VMs.
2. In the Sharing window, right click on your VM ->Manage -> Share the VM; I chose default options.
3. In the same gui, under 'Shared VMs' tab, click 'Manage Auto Start'

That's all it took! And now I am able to launch the VMWare Workstation GUI after the host system reboots.

PS. I posted the Question here because I was originally using a script to achieve this; I thought there could be more scripts/programming solutions. Also, Expert Exchange maybe a competition but it provided me full solution yesterday without requiring any login; so, being a once paying member there, I had assumed that they have now become a 'free' site. But today their link doesn't work.

Comment: Although the link you provided might answer your question, you should post the core information here as external links might become invalid in future; furthermore, if all this is the solution for your problem you should consider to accept your own answer...

Comment: Ah, the irony of a link to EE as an answer on a site whose *literal purpose for being* is to kill off EE.

Comment: @aschipfl: Or, more to the point, the external link is *invalid right this minute*; E-E appears to no longer care about keeping answers buried somewhere deep in the page where no one will normally see them and now just makes them utterly inaccessible.

Comment: And therefore, this answer is not useful. -1 until you paste the details from there to here.